# PHP How do I retrieve images that are stored outside of the document root with MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, image, document-root

I'm really confused about php fileuploading securely and retrieving those files.  I'm told to store uploaded images outside of document root for security reasons.  I can upload okay, but I'm not sure I know how best to serve those images given my MYSQL and HTML structure.  This may be a stupid way of doing this but here's my problem:

I have 5 images stored within my document root.  In my MYSQL database i store a URL path to that image (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/images/123.jpg).  My HTML index will query MYSQL and select the image path and then list all of the paths to the images and then the images display.

However I have images stored outside my document root (for security reasons).  Is there a way that I can store into MYSQL a URL path like www.mywebsite.com/images/outofroot.jpg and then do a select query like i did above?

Comment: you would server them with a php script as the img src. the script does have access outside the root. `<img src="script.php?image_id">`

Comment: i'm a little new to php.  what does it mean to "server them with a php script?"  what is in script.php?  and how does that relate to "?image_id"?

Comment: does this make it clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855135/best-way-to-limit-access-to-images-is-this-about-right

Comment: For this suggestion, I would store them in the db as a server path like /path/outside/of/docroot/image.jpg for example, then in the PHP script you can grab the file from the path. The image id would correspond to the record in the database so you weren't passing a path to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what these aforementioned "security reasons" you mentioned were, so if you could clarify, that would be great!

My php is a little rusty, but from what I remember you should do something like this for a jpeg:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("/path/to/file.jpg");
imagejpeg($img);
```

First off, we set the `header` to match that of a jpeg image. Next, we load an image into memory with `imagecreatefromjpeg`. Finally we serve the image with `imagejpeg`

This example is only limited to jpegs, depending on your use, you may need other types. You could write some logic (as an exercise ;)) to have this work for other types. Check out `imagepng`, `imagegif` and others in the PHP documentation for information how to do this.

If you need to have some kind of security checks, (e.g. the user must be authorized to see the picture) then storing them outside of the working directory and loading them like this is a great idea.

However, if the images you are serving do not need any permission checking to access, then you're better off serving them normally, rather than have a middle man to serve them.

Comment: well, I'm starting a social site where users upload pictures of themselves and share images.  i thought that storing the images off root and making them viewable only to members of the community would be a good security precaution.  do you think i need to store the pictures outside of the working directory?

Comment: Although permissions can be set up with your web server to prevent people from accessing these files directly, it's much easier and less error prone to store them outside of your working directory.

If you're using Apache and don't want to store them outside of the working directory, there was a similar problem posted earlier for handling such a situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605078/how-to-restrict-forbid-access-to-specific-file-types-such-as-js-css-inside-a